# React Linking.addEventListener runs a Firebase sign in link twice in a useEffect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have the following function to authenticate a user with React Native (Expo) and Firebase:

```
export default function AuthenticateUser() {
  const user = useStore((state) => state.user); // Gets the user from state
  const setUser = useStore((state) => state.setUser);
  const setLoadingUser = useStore((state) => state.setLoadingUser);
  const [GQL_getOrCreateUser] = useMutation(getOrCreateUser); // GraphQL function

  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribe: any;
    let urlHandler: any;

    function handleUrl(event: any) {
      const { url }: { url: string } = event;
      if (url.includes('/account')) {
        const isSignInWithEmailLink = firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(url);
        if (isSignInWithEmailLink) {
          AsyncStorage.getItem('unverifiedEmail').then((email) => {
            if (email) {
              firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithEmailLink(email, url)
                .then(() => {
                  // We are signed in
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  // Failed to sign in
                });
            } else {
              // Missing pending email from AsyncStorage
            }
          });
        }
      };
    }

    function handleLinking(userDetails: User) {
      urlHandler = ({ url }: { url: string }) => {
        handleUrl({ url, userDetails });
      };
      // Listen to incoming deep link when app first opens
      Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
        if (url) {
          handleUrl({ url, userDetails });
        }
      });
      // Listen to incoming deep link while app is open
      Linking.addEventListener('url', urlHandler);
    }

    if (!user) {
      unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((authenticatedUser) => {
        setLoadingUser(false);
        if (authenticatedUser) {
          const uid = authenticatedUser.uid;
          const phoneNumber = authenticatedUser.phoneNumber;
          let email: string;
          if (authenticatedUser.email) {
            email = authenticatedUser.email;
          } else {
            // retreiving email from AsyncStorage. We add it there when requesting a passwordless sign in link email, as recommended by Firebase.
            AsyncStorage.getItem('unverifiedEmail').then((unverifiedEmail) => {
              email = unverifiedEmail ? unverifiedEmail : '';
            });
          }
          const emailVerified = authenticatedUser.emailVerified;
          // Updating user record with GraphQL
          GQL_getOrCreateUser({ variables: { uid, phoneNumber } })
            .then(async (document) => {
              const data = document.data.getOrCreateUser;
              const userDetails = { ...data, phoneNumber, email, emailVerified }
              setUser(userDetails); // Setting the stateful user record
              handleLinking(userDetails); // Handle deeplink
            })
            .catch(() => {
              // GraphQL failed
            });
        }
      });
    }
    return () => {
      unsubscribe?.();
      // Removing event listener;
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', urlHandler);
    };
  }, [GQL_getOrCreateUser, setLoadingUser, setUser, user]);
}
```

My problem is that the sign in method runs too often resulting in unexpected behavior.
I suspect it is caused by re-rendering triggered by the user auth state and the GraphQL running (GraphQL call to get or create a user causes three renders, which seems to be how it should behave).

I use deeplinking to handle passwordless email sign-in (`firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(url)`)
The URL is detected with either Linking.getInitialURL (when the deeplink opens the app) or `Linking.addEventListener('url', handler)` when the app is already running.

**As example, let's take scenario 1: Linking.getInitialUrl**

1. I click the link. It asks to open the app.
2. The app opens
3. The user is not logged in (user is not in the app state) so the code inside the `if (!user)` is triggered.
4. The user email is in AsyncStorage because we just requested the login link email and I save it when the user asks for it.
5. GraphQL fetches the user and causes two more renders
6. I set the user in state with setUser and run handleLinking.
7. Because the app was closed, `getInitialURL` for the URL is triggered and it goes correctly through the steps and signs me in.
   HOWEVER, `handleLinking` runs a second time (possibly the extra two renders caused by GraphQL trigger a `Linking.addEventListener` event to fire?) and returns an error because the sign in link cannot be used a second time.

I think there is a fundamental flow in my logic. What is it? How can this be improved and done correctly?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: I don't see any dependencies in your useEffect!

Comment: @FotisTsakiris look better. It's there: `[GQL_getOrCreateUser, setLoadingUser, setUser, user]`

Answer (score 0):

If any of the objects in your `useEffect` dependency changes, then the `useEffect` function will re-run. So if your `useEffect` callback runs too often, the dependency array is where you should look at.

It is important to know that a "change" can be a simple as an object being reinstantiated or a function being re-created, even though the underlying value remains the same.

Comment: I realize the core issue is in the dependencies, most likely. I also mentioned it. I'm trying to see if someone has a different logic in mind which will work better and explain how they would do it differently.